# Dialogflow Intent that will display additional text to that which is spoken

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have created a simple conversational flow in Dialogflow that accepts various questions and speaks pre-programmed replies, all defined in a series of intents. There are no external hooks etc.

When used on a screen based device (eg. mobile phone) I want to display more text than that which is spoken. (displayText) eg:

User: "What colour is the sky?"
Bot: "Blue" (spoken and displayed on screen). "At night it is black". (Additional information displayed on screen only.)

I want to do the same for each intent.

What is the simplest way of achieving that please? I would prefer to keep most of it in Dialogflow and to write the minimum amount of code possible.

Comment: When you say "than that which is spoken", which integration are you using that will speak the text?

Comment: Purely Dialogflow. I am looking for a simple way to extend that with a bit of additional unspoken text.

Comment: I understand you're saying Dialogflow, but which integration (https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations) are you expecting to speak? Actions on Google? Facebook? Something else? What will be the user be using to talk to Dialogflow? Dialogflow is a tool to build for multiple integrations. Which one(s) do you expect will speak?

Answer (score 0):

It is ok, I found the solution thanks. In Dialogflow intents under Response there are two tabs, Default and Google Assistant. Under Google Assistant there is an option Customise audio output. When you select that you get two input fields, one for text and one for speech.

So to use the above example under intent training phrase I entered "What colour is the sky?"

Under Default Response I entered "Blue"

Under Google Assistant response, Text Output field I entered: "Blue. At night it is black."

Under Google Assistant response, Speech Output field I entered: "Blue".

It works perfectly in both Google Home (voice only) and Assistant on mobile phone (Speaks "Blue" but displays "Blue. At night it is black.")

It doesn't even seem necessary to enter anything in Default Response. It works fine on Google Home and Assistant on the phone without it. Not sure about other platforms though.